# Django login does not show anything

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I have sign in, sign up and log out in my home page. Sign up works fine but login does not work. when i run the server it works but does not show anything, any errors or anything in login page that prompts the user to enter username and password.

views.py

```
def userLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home') 
        else:
            error = True
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error}) 

    return render(request, 'login.html',)
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
    <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/$', Home, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^product_upload', InsertProduct, name = 'product_upload'),
    url(r'^success', success, name = 'success'),
    path('productlist/', ShowProducts, name = 'productlist'),
    path('<int:product_id>/', product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    url(r'^signup/$', signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', userLogin, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', userLogout, name='logout'),
]
```

You can see images below:

[Sign Up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEfWf.png)

[Sign In image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrEES.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 return render(request, 'login.html',)
```

This line just renders the HTML without passing any data, you are missing a context including the form to render.

or you could use a class based view designed for the login: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView

Answer (score 0):

You should define `<form mehtod="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">` in your login.html and aslo try `request.POST.get('username')` and `request.POST.get('password')`